# $(document).ready not firing when returning view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a script that executes correctly when I first open my view. It enables and disables controls based on the values in my model.

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

After I submit my form,

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
        {
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    ...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }

            return this.View("Index", model);
        }
```

I want my script to be executed again, but it doesn't happen. How can I archieve this? I tried adding this script:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
        //execute code
    });
```

But to no avail. It will executed before my view is returned. I need to execute the script after my view is returned.

Comment: Are you preventing form submit or not?

Comment: No I'm not. I want my JS to execute after my view is returned.

Comment: So you are refreshing/redirecting page. You have then to include script in new page. If submiting form refresh same page, then it should work so not sure what is your issue (be aware, i'm not asp developper, so i'm not sure what exactly do you mean by view)

Comment: I am submitting a form and refreshing the same page. I've put a breakpoint in my `$(document).ready(function () { ...` body... It just doesn't get there when my page is refreshed.

Comment: The page contains several partial views, but even when the code is in my main view the problem persists.

Comment: document.ready will be fired every time a page loads (whether that is after a post or not) so it should fire. Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in my console. It loads when I first open the page. It loads when I manually press "F5". It does not load after submitting the form and having my controller return my view (which is the same page).

Comment: You need to include more view code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function and put all your code in it.

```
<script>

         BindPageLoadEvents();  
         //This funciton will automatically call when your page loads first time, 
         //and also after your submit.  


    function BindPageLoadEvents(){
         ////Put all your page load (document.ready) events and binding here, in this method.
    }

<script>
```

I really don't know your real scenario but from your given explanation i hope this will help you.

Comment: You say that BindPageLoadEvents() will call after my submit, the problem is this doesn't happen.

Comment: make sure to put it directly in **script tag**. not in **document.ready**

Comment: and for test you can add alert in BindPageLoadEvents() so each time it will called it will alert on screen

Comment: the code above should work without this workaround. The issue lies somewhere else.